# Azure SAS expiry while copying blobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

What should be an ideal expiry time for SAS. The SAS url is to be used to copy blobs from one container to another (different storage account also possible).
The copy command is called immediately after generating SAS, so is the expiry time just needed for the start of blob copy or should it be valid until the copy blob is completed?

```
sas_signature = source_blob_object.generate_container_shared_access_signature(source_container, ContainerPermissions.READ, expiry = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours = 1))
blob_url = source_blob_object.make_blob_url(source_container, blob_name, sas_token = sas_signature)
response = dest_blob_object.copy_blob(dest_container, blob_name, blob_url,
standard_blob_tier = dest_access_tier, rehydrate_priority = rehyd_priority)
```

Comment: Regarding the issue, the SAS token should expire after you complete the copy. Because when copying, we need to continue to read blob data. so please set the expiration time of the sas token to be greater than the copy time or you directly [use the account key to copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651890/how-to-copy-a-file-in-azure-from-a-one-storage-account-to-another-using-python).

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: Account key can only be directly be used if the containers are in same storage account or if the Blobs are public. Right?

Comment: Account key is just access key. You can use it to manage resources in the storage account. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-manage#access-keys.

Comment: @JimXu Please post the above inputs as an answer so it helps others in the community who have similar queries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT According to your need,  I'm summarizing the answer:

The SAS token should expire after the copy is completed. Because when copying, we need to continue to read blob data and write blob to data. So please set the expiration time of the sas token to be greater than the copy time or you directly [use account key to copy blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651890/how-to-copy-a-file-in-azure-from-a-one-storage-account-to-another-using-python). Besides the account key is just access key. You can use it to manage resources in the storage account. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-manage#access-keys)